# VNC Viewer Disconnect or Click Ctrl Alt Del makes the screen black

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

**CLIENT**
my VNC Viewer is on OS X EL Capitain 10.11.6

**SERVER**

My target server is  kali 4.15.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.15.11-1kali1 (2018-03-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Desktop Session  is lightdm-xsession

**ISSUE**

Initially session works fine but after the session either **auto disconnect** or if i hit **CTRL ALT DEL** button on the VNC Viewer itself the whole screen goes black

Hitting CTRL ALT DEL on the following toolbar is having the same issue

[image: VNC VIEWER TOOLBAR]

I haven't been able to find a way to recover out of it.

**WORKAROUND**

The only thing that is working for me is SSH > Reboot

Comment: The issue is really it's getting locked, Same issue can be reproduced by choose the lock option from the menu, i just don't know how to unlock it to bring it back to the login screen

Comment: i did updated my power settings to never lock or blank screen but still would like to know how to recover from a lock situation

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with two Ubuntu machines.

CTRL+ALT+DELETE basically logs you out of / locks your session.

The solution was, to initiate another VNC session to the second virtual display where the lockscreen resides.

In the following I will call the machine with VNC-viewer client and the one running VNC server server.

1. Ssh into the server, and indentify if there is a secondary display created lockscreen:

`ps -ef | grep dm`  or  `ps -aux | grep dm`

and look for GDM\KDM\LightDM processes and their parameters. In my case, the locked session was on display :0, which was black over VNC. And there was a process with parameter :1. This was a new virtual display created for lockscreen.

[Process list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM1mu.png)

In the picture gtk-greeter marks that the system created a login prompt and :1 is the new display.

2. At this point the task is to create a secondary VNC server process on the server, which serves the display for the lockscreen.

From the man page of x11vnc:

> XDM/GDM/KDM: if you are running x11vnc as root and want
> to find the XAUTHORITY before anyone has logged into an X session yet, use: x11vnc -env FD_XDM=1 -auth guess ... (This will also find the XAUTHORITY if a user is already logged into the X session.) When running as root, FD_XDM=1 will be tried if the initial -auth guess fails.

So, I had to use `-env FD_XDM=1` and `-display :1` options for the new server process. Also needed an unused tcp port to connect to. So, the full command was something like this:

`sudo /usr/bin/x11vnc -env FD_XDM=1 -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5958 -shared -display :1`

rfbport tells the server to listen on 5958\tcp. Choose any free tcp port.

rfbauth tells the VNC server to ask for password. You may omit this one.

3. From the client connect to server:5958 with VNC-viewer. It shows the lockscreen. Unlock the server. As soon you have hit enter, the virtual display :1 is destroyed and VNC connection is hanged up. Go back to ssh and close the secondary VNC server with CTRL+C.
4. Now you should be able to connect to the original VNC server.